# Is there any faster way to check if a number is a integral power of 2 in c++

Tags: c++

I know this method and it is not efficient enough

```
(a/2)%2==0;
```

Comment: Depending on  the size of a - you could do a single bit compare, checking for the values 2,4,8,16,32,64 etc.

Comment: A division and a modulo, that's already pretty efficient! Have you benchmarked and determined this to be a bottleneck?

Comment: `(12 / 2) % 2 = 0`. 12 is not integral power of 2.

Comment: actually I am getting Time Limit Exceeded in a competitive programming problem

Comment: @g.ijoe Is that because there's a loop somewhere?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight :Yes there are plenty of loops

Comment: @SouravGhosh :Problem is to convert one number in minimum operations into another

Comment: @g.ijoe he means [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282). Btw your way to check power of 2 is completely incorrect. And that expression should easily optimize out by the compiler, so it shouldn't take much time. If it takes long time to run, measure or profile it

Comment: Don't tag C++ questions [tag:c].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method does not check that. It will return true for 12 for example.(and will return false for 2)

To check you may use `x != 0 && (x & (x - 1)) == 0`

Comment: Heh.. we came up with the same example...

Comment: @EugenSh. it's smallest multiple of 4, which is not is power of two, so it's quite natural

Answer (score 6):

See the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) :

```
unsigned int v; // we want to see if v is a power of 2
bool f;         // the result goes here 

f = (v & (v - 1)) == 0;
```

> Note that 0 is incorrectly considered a power of 2 here. To remedy this, use:

```
f = v && !(v & (v - 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using gcc and x64 there's an intrinsic that lets you use the CPU instruction that counts bits:

```
int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)
```

Comment: How can the population count be used to determine whether a number is to the power of 2?

Comment: @DarkDust values that are a power of 2 have only one bit set

Comment: Right. So obvious it hurts…